# How to install mysql-client manually

Tags: mysql, webserver

I had many problems with mysql latest version so i decided to manually install lower mysql version on my ubuntu using this gist

https://gist.github.com/ahmadhasankhan/48fc9fc9a19807daef1622751a56884b

Now how can i install `mysql-client` without disturbing anything ? can i just do `apt install mysql-client` ? or it will ruin everything ?

PS: i want to use `mysql-client` for using `mysqldump`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome, maybe you can tell us what the problems you are referring are.

Comment: well my mysql is having a problem with one the web app, installing lower version is fine, can you please tell if i can install mysql client ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Client won't disturb your MySQL Server installation, if that is what you are referring to.

Client can be installed and used without server component, and versions of the two don't need to match necessarily.

You may lack a feature or bugfix, but in general if all you need is dump, it should work between versions.

Comment: using mysqldump shows me this error `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'xxx' AND TABLE_NAME = 'xxx';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)`

Comment: This should hekp you: https://serverfault.com/questions/912162/mysqldump-throws-unknown-table-column-statistics-in-information-schema-1109